# Does Rascal Java method AST also contain super() Expression for calls to super with arguments?

Tags: rascal

When I look at Java method AST declaration in Rascal, I see under Expression `\super()` node.

However in Java, you can also call `super()` with parameters. So, I expected to see something like : `\super(list[Expression] arguments)`, but I do not see it.

Is it traced via `\methodCall()` or in some other way?

I could not try it myself because I get an error when I try to build an AST from a constructor with `getMethodASTEclipse()` method. I already opened an issue about this `getMethodASTEclipse()` error in the GitHub.

Comment: Is this related to this issue: https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/issues/486 ?

Comment: No, the issue in the github you're mentioning ([link](https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/issues/486)} is about not being able to build an AST for a constructor without arguments.

Comment: This stackexchange question is about the following: given an AST, if there is a super(param1, param2) call in the code with parameters, how do we visit that node? What I now know is that we can visit it with \constructorCall(isSuper,_,_). The remaining question, then, is: what is super() node used or visited for?

Comment: Aha, so you have answered the question, but now a new question appears, why it `super()` in the AST? could is be the `super.invokeMethod()` expression? that the receiver is `super()`?

Comment: For the following code:

Comment: (perhaps update the question?)

Comment: For the following Java code: `super.p11();` the Rascal AST contains only `methodCall(_,_,_)` with no receiver. So, no, I don't think `super()` is used in the `super.invokeMethod()` as receiver. Do you know an example for which `super()` in Rascal AST is used?

Comment: May be we can close this question and I can ask it as a new question...

Comment: closing it is an good idea :) (and opening a new specific question!)

Comment: This question is closed. I have opened a new question as follow-up : <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039813/why-is-the-expression-super-in-the-java-ast-in-rascal>