# Why is the expression `super()` in the Java AST in Rascal?

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, rascal

One of the expressions in the [Java AST declaration](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Libraries/lang/java/m3/AST/Declaration/Declaration.html) is `Expression::super()`. 
For which Java expression(s) is `super()` used?

Take this example class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SuperTests<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    public SuperTests() {
        super();
    }
    public SuperTests(int capacity) {
        super(capacity);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        super.clear();
    }

    public <T extends Integer> void addSupers(List<? super T> list) {

    }
}
```

The AST in rascal is:

```
compilationUnit(
  [
    import("java.util.ArrayList")[
      @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(0,27,<1,0>,<1,27>)
    ],
    import("java.util.List")[
      @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(28,22,<2,0>,<2,22>)
    ]
  ],
  [class(
      "SuperTests",
      [parameterizedType(simpleType(simpleName("ArrayList")[
              @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(87,9,<4,35>,<4,44>),
              @decl=|java+class:///java/util/ArrayList|,
              @typ=class(
                |java+class:///java/util/ArrayList|,
                [typeArgument(|java+typeVariable:///SuperTests/T|)])
            ]))],
      [],
      [
        constructor(
          "SuperTests",
          [],
          [],
          block([constructorCall(
                true,
                [])[
                @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(128,8,<7,2>,<7,10>),
                @decl=|java+constructor:///java/util/ArrayList/ArrayList()|
              ]])[
            @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(124,15,<6,21>,<8,2>)
          ])[
          @modifiers=[public()],
          @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(104,35,<6,1>,<8,2>),
          @decl=|java+constructor:///SuperTests/SuperTests()|,
          @typ=constructor(
            |java+constructor:///SuperTests/SuperTests()|,
            [])
        ],
        constructor(
          "SuperTests",
          [parameter(
              int(),
              "capacity",
              0)[
              @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(159,12,<9,19>,<9,31>),
              @decl=|java+parameter:///SuperTests/SuperTests(int)/capacity|,
              @typ=int()
            ]],
          [],
          block([constructorCall(
                true,
                [simpleName("capacity")[
                    @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(183,8,<10,8>,<10,16>),
                    @decl=|java+parameter:///SuperTests/SuperTests(int)/capacity|,
                    @typ=int()
                  ]])[
                @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(177,16,<10,2>,<10,18>),
                @decl=|java+constructor:///java/util/ArrayList/ArrayList(int)|
              ]])[
            @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(173,23,<9,33>,<11,2>)
          ])[
          @modifiers=[public()],
          @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(141,55,<9,1>,<11,2>),
          @decl=|java+constructor:///SuperTests/SuperTests(int)|,
          @typ=constructor(
            |java+constructor:///SuperTests/SuperTests(int)|,
            [int()])
        ],
        method(
          void(),
          "clear",
          [],
          [],
          block([expressionStatement(methodCall(
                  true,
                  "clear",
                  [])[
                  @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(234,13,<15,2>,<15,15>),
                  @decl=|java+method:///java/util/ArrayList/clear()|,
                  @typ=void()
                ])[
                @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(234,14,<15,2>,<15,16>)
              ]])[
            @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(230,21,<14,21>,<16,2>)
          ])[
          @modifiers=[
            annotation(markerAnnotation("Override")[
                @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(199,9,<13,1>,<13,10>),
                @typ=interface(
                  |java+interface:///java/lang/Override|,
                  [])
              ]),
            public()
          ],
          @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(199,52,<13,1>,<16,2>),
          @decl=|java+method:///SuperTests/clear()|,
          @typ=method(
            |java+method:///SuperTests/clear()|,
            [],
            void(),
            [])
        ],
        method(
          void(),
          "addSupers",
          [parameter(
              parameterizedType(simpleType(simpleName("List")[
                    @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(297,4,<18,43>,<18,47>),
                    @decl=|java+interface:///java/util/List|,
                    @typ=interface(
                      |java+interface:///java/util/List|,
                      [wildcard(super([typeArgument(|java+typeVariable:///SuperTests/addSupers(java/util/List)/T|)]))])
                  ])),
              "list",
              0)[
              @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(297,20,<18,43>,<18,63>),
              @decl=|java+parameter:///SuperTests/addSupers(java.util.List)/list|,
              @typ=interface(
                |java+interface:///java/util/List|,
                [wildcard(super([typeArgument(|java+typeVariable:///SuperTests/addSupers(java/util/List)/T|)]))])
            ]],
          [],
          block([])[
            @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(319,7,<18,65>,<20,2>)
          ])[
          @modifiers=[public()],
          @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(255,71,<18,1>,<20,2>),
          @decl=|java+method:///SuperTests/addSupers(java.util.List)|,
          @typ=method(
            |java+method:///SuperTests/addSupers(java.util.List)|,
            [typeParameter(
                |java+typeVariable:///SuperTests/addSupers(java/util/List)/T|,
                extends([class(
                      |java+class:///java/lang/Integer|,
                      [])]))],
            void(),
            [interface(
                |java+interface:///java/util/List|,
                [wildcard(super([typeArgument(|java+typeVariable:///SuperTests/addSupers(java/util/List)/T|)]))])])
        ]
      ])[
      @modifiers=[public()],
      @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(52,278,<4,0>,<23,1>),
      @decl=|java+class:///SuperTests|,
      @typ=class(
        |java+class:///SuperTests|,
        [typeParameter(
            |java+typeVariable:///SuperTests/T|,
            unbounded())])
    ]])[
  @src=|project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(0,331,<1,0>,<23,2>),
  @decl=|java+compilationUnit:///src/SuperTests.java|,
  @messages=[
    warning(
      "The serializable class SuperTests does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long",
      |project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(65,10,<4,0>,<4,0>)),
    warning(
      "The type parameter T is hiding the type T",
      |project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(263,1,<18,0>,<18,0>)),
    warning(
      "The type parameter T should not be bounded by the final type Integer. Final types cannot be further extended",
      |project://TestThing/src/SuperTests.java|(273,7,<18,0>,<18,0>))
  ]
]
```

It does not contain the `super()` constructor with no arguments. Only in case of the wildcard bound (`wildcard(super(`) is there a `super(_)` but it has one argument and is described in the `lang::java::m3::TypeSymbol` module.

So what is happening, is there a Java construct I'm missing, or is the Rascal ADT definition incorrect with respect to what is generated in the AST?

Comment: What has this got to do with Rascal?  You need to be able to isolate your issues, or you will find the climate involved, too.

Comment: This question is about the Java AST declaration in Rascal language. For the Java AST nodes in Rascal, please see: <http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Libraries/lang/java/m3/AST/Declaration/Declaration.html>. This is mainly a Rascal question for this reason. It is about how Rascal does Java source code analysis.

Comment: @caytekin I think if you would list the constructs of java you have already looked at people would be less aggressive. More context see this comment:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112464/does-rascal-java-method-ast-also-contain-super-expression-for-calls-to-super-w#comment42288952_21112464

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't used to represent any Java expression anymore. It is a part of the code before we decided to change how super constructor invocation and super method invocation are represented in the Java AST in Rascal.

All constructor calls are represented by `constructorCall(bool isSuper, _)`. A value of true in the `isSuper` field indicates that it is a super call. Similarly, all method calls are represented by `methodCall(bool isSuper,_)` with the same logic.

The `wildcard(_)` and `super(_)` from `lang::java::m3::TypeSymbol` are used to represent type information that is used in ASTs as well as M3.